# Pointers and the Memory Pool: Simple Test Program

Tags: c, malloc, function-pointers

I am just trying to teach myself how to create, mutate pass pointers and using blocks of memory from the memory pool. What I am attempting to due in my program below is return a pointer to a block of memory from the memory pool (that I `malloc`ed), however it is giving me an error. If anyone could point me in the right direction by explaining my error, showing me how to fix it (or lead me in the right direction) then that would be fantastic!

Here is the code I have right now (and further below is my error message):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int EnemyLife(int level)
{
    int RandTime;
    int *ptr;
    srand(time(NULL));
    ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*level);

    for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i)
    {
        RandTime = rand() % 100;
        *ptr++ = RandTime;
    }

    return *ptr;
};

int main(void)
{
    int Ammount, RandValue;
    int (*PtrEnemyLife) (int) = EnemyLife;

    printf("Ammount of random number printed to the screen?\n");

    scanf("%d", &Ammount);

    int *ptr;

    *ptr = (*PtrEnemyLife) (Ammount);
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

... and this is the error I get after a peer advised me to compile using the `-Wall` flag.

```
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand.c:39:7: warning: ‘ptr’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand: In function `EnemyLife':
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand.c:8: multiple definition of `EnemyLife'
/tmp/ccvZvKYA.o:/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand.c:8: first defined here
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand: In function `main':
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand.c:28: multiple definition of `main'
/tmp/ccvZvKYA.o:/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand.c:28: first defined here
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
/home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand:(.data+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in /home/definity/Desktop/Cloud/code/rand(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few errors here. I have added comments within the snippet of code to explain what I am doing at each step, compare it to your original code and see why I did what I did. The following is what I think you are attempting to do (attempting to follow your logic):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int *enemyLife( int const level ) {
  // Requests a block of memory of size int * level from the 
  // memory pool.
  int *ptr = malloc( sizeof( int ) * level );

  // Determines if we ran out of memory from the memory pool. Important 
  // to always check the result from a system call.
  if ( ptr == NULL ) {
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  srand( time( NULL ) );

  // Iterates level times and stores a random number in the pointer ptr 
  // at the ith position.
  for ( int i = 0; i < level; i++ ) {
    ptr[ i ] = ( rand() % 100 ); // Side: ptr[ i ] => *( ptr + i )
  }

  // Returning a POINTER to an integer.
  return ptr;
}

int main( void ) {
  int amount;

  printf( "Amount of random numbers printed to the screen?\n" );
  scanf( "%d", &amount );

  // Defining a pointer to an integer ptr and storing the result from 
  // enemyLife in the pointer. Passing "amount" because we want that many 
  // numbers.
  int *ptr = enemyLife( amount );

  printf( "Outputting those random values.\n" );

  // Iterate over every position in the returned pointer to get each random 
  // number. Output it to stdout.
  for ( int i = 0; i < amount; i++ ) {
    printf( "%d\n", ptr[ i ] );
  }

  // Free the memory block that ptr points to. We no longer need it.
  free( ptr );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I take away the *ptr is get the following error:
22:2: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: @user1704227, make `EnemyLife` return an `int *` not an `int` (hence a pointer instead of an integer).

Comment: @user1704227, if you get time review the code I posted to see why it works and compare it in detail to your original code. Then, next time you make a program involving pointers and memory from the memory pool you will have no problem creating it without errors :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int *EnemyLife(int level) // here  you return  a pointer
{

    int RandTime;
    int *ptr;
    srand(time(NULL));
    ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*level);

    for (int i = 0; i < level; ++i)
    {
        RandTime = rand() % 100;
        *(ptr+i) = RandTime;         // keep ptr pointer the start address
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Aslo:

```
  int* (*PtrEnemyLife) (int) = EnemyLife;

  ptr = (*PtrEnemyLife)(amount);
  Or just:
  ptr = PtrEnemyLife(amount);
```

Add     `free (ptr);` at the end of main

Answer (score 0):

here are the things you've got wrong :

1. you have to return a pointer but you're returning the content of the first pointer you've initialized (it's not illegal but I don't think that this is what you want to do) instead you should write `return ptr;`
2. when you pass `amount` to the `enemylife` function it's not the number of elements to print on the screen but the number of ints to be stored in the allocated space.
3. in the main function you're just printing the content of the first initialized pointer.
4. the function `ptrEnemyLife` is just a waist of memory space.